# how to display repeating csv values only once

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and I want to know what code can I use to display a repeating values in my csv file only once

for example:

example.csv: green, green, green, blue, red, red, yellow:

the out put I want is:

the colours are : green, blue, red, yellow

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the order, you can use [sets](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_sets.asp)

```
set(['green', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'red', 'red', 'yellow'])
```